# mysql Union query return the same column name in php array

Tags: php, mysql

I write a code to fetch data from Mysql Database with union to select multiple data from different table the result is ok but the column name is the same name

```
    <?php
        $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("musicstore");
        $strSQL = "select count(song_Id) as 'cnts' from song  where date_rel = CURDATE()  
union select count(album_id) as 'cnta' from album ";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
        $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
        $resultArray = array();
        while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
        {
            $arrCol = array();
            for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
            {
                $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
            }
            array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);

        }

        mysql_close($objConnect);

        echo json_encode($resultArray);

    ?>
```

the result is `[{"cnts":"38"},{"cnts":"3"}]`

I don't know why it's doesn't get a column name from defined name

Comment: The returned aliased column name, each side of your union, is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dummy columns to achieve this.

```
$strSQL = " select count(song_Id) as 'cnts', 'cnta' from song  where date_rel = CURDATE()  
union select 'cnta', count(album_id) as 'cnta' from album " ;
```